# Why add three and then do a binary AND NOT operation

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Some code I am looking at (to write a Targa file) has (with no explanation) the following line:

`int row_size = ((m_info.window_width * 3 + 3) & ~3);`

Every number I have tried comes out the same if you did not do the  `+ 3) & ~ 3);` part.

Can someone tell me why you would do this?

Comment: It's a trick to round up to the nearest multiple of 4. `+3` to bump up, `~3` to zero out two lowest-order bits (producing a number that's a multiple of 4). Try it with a few numbers, you'll see how it works.

Comment: ^ This could be an answer!

Comment: Same thing you'd do for BMP files since they also have a padding requirement. Not sure what numbers you're trying, but this makes it easy to see. https://ideone.com/xQR4iu